# Bisector Intersection Proof

Tags: geometry, angle

[image]
$AGF$ is a triangle, $B$ is the center of its inscribed circle, and $D$ and $E$ are the intersections of that circle with $[AG]$ & $[AF]$ respectively. I couldn’t figure out how to prove that the perpendicular bisector of $[AD]$, the perpendicular bisector of $[AE]$, and the angular bisector of $\widehat{GAF}$ intersect. ($H$ on the figure). Do you know how to prove this intersection?
Thank you in advance!

---

https://www.geogebra.org/m/fhge9wjr

Comment: $\Delta DAE$ is isosceles. So the angle bisector of $GAF$ is the same as the perpendicular bisector of $DE$.

Comment: $H$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Triangles $\color{brown} {ADB}$ and $\color{red}{AEB}$ are equal (two equal angles and a common side).

Therefore $$AE=AD$$
Consider the symmetry $s$ with respect to $AB$.
$$s(D)=E$$

Let $d$, the perpendicular bisector of $[AD]$ and $e$
, the perpendicular bisector of $[AE]$
$$s(d)=e$$
So $d, e$ and and the angular bisector of $\widehat{GAF}$
intersect.

Answer (score 1):

One proof is that perpendicular bisectors of $AD$ and $AE$ meet at the circumcenter of $\triangle{ADE}$. Therefore $HD=HE$, (and $AD=AE$)*, and all points equidistant from two lines that meet at a point fall on the angle bisector of those lines.

- for DS: since $DB=BE$ and $AB$ is shared and $\angle{ADB}, \angle{AEB}$ are right angles, by HL theorem $\triangle{ADB}=\triangle{AEB}$, $AD=DE$, i.e., $ADBE$ is a kite.

Comment: @DS why the objection? The proof (and my statement) is correct. And $HE$ definitely equals $HD$ by construction.

Comment: $HE = HD$, but how do you show $H$ is equidistant from $AD$ and $AE$?

Comment: At any rate, your edit boils down to my comment on the question. And earlier, the congruency was clear to me, but may not have been to the OP,

Comment: Also, my first (deleted) comment mistakenly included $HD \neq HE$, sorry for that.

Comment: @DS no worries, always good to have critical eyes on things, and of course all these answers are stressing different points of a shared truth. As this person prepares for an Olympiad, it's good for them to think of angle bisectors as points equidistant from lines (and from any pair of points in those lines equidistant from the intersection), and vice versa (any point on a bisector is equidistant from any pair of points on lines equidistant from the intersection). Intelligenti pauca stresses proportionality, you the equality of tangents from a point outside a circle. The OP learns from each.